# How to enable VoLTE in Samsung Galaxy S7 in india...?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s7

I have a galaxy s7 bought from uae.I need to enable volte services for reliance jio in india.
 It was having android noughat 7.0 uae version. I tried to install indian version noughat 7.0 which  gave me an error of "SW VER CHECKFAIL....... "

after googling a lot i understood that boatloader cant be downgraded to previous version. unfortunately i think the latest indian version is far behind the uae version.

So i just omitted BL file while odin installation and flashed the rom. Then i dont have imei and mobile network became unusable.

Now i flashed latest Malaysia version oreo (android 8). But still volte is not working..
Any idea whats happening...?

Comment: try to insert sim in Sim1 slot

Answer (score 0):

Samsung Galaxy s7 is an LTE device and not VoLTE. But if you still want to make voice calls over LTE, you can download jio 4G voice app from https://www.jio.com/en-in/apps/jio-4g-voice  .

It is very user friendly app,still in its beta phase. But it lets you enjoy all the features of VoLTE while you are in LTE.